# How to stop VMWare Host that keeps going into pause mode?

Tags: vmware-server

Every so often while doing some work in a test/lab environment I've been having some of the servers or clients being paused in VMWare and it's been driving me a bit nuts.

In the event log they show up as "Virtual machine is suspended" by the user "User" who doesn't exist.

This then gets in the way of some other events, such as powering off the machine, because it won't start the machine from suspend to power it down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In proposing this question I think I found my answer [Stop the system from entering standby mode](https://serverfault.com/questions/31942/stop-the-system-from-entering-standby-mode)

The power settings on the machines being suspended was to go into hibernate.

But, even though this is the case, is there some way of having the power off automation resume the slept PC before powering down rather than just leaving it suspended?

Answer (score 1):

Alternative approach -  (vmware/esx client) if have access to/ From Management console :
- Turn off the target VM, then do "edit Setting" .
- under "options" , select "power Management" 
then deselect "suspend the virtual machine" (is selected!)
and select "put the guest OS into standbay mode and leave the virtual machine powered on".

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Every time I do this, it reverts back to "suspend the virtual machine".